# Why aren't all the werewolves turning at the same time?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-vampire-diaries

In the *Vampire Diaries* [S02E21](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sun_Also_Rises), *The Sun Also Rises*, when Klaus's main werewolf turns, why doesn't Klaus himself and his backup werewolf also turn at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

First off, the easy one: at this point in the show, Klaus is still under the curse his mother put on him that suppresses his werewolf side. That's the whole point of the season -- Klaus's trying to break his curse. Note that, as the curse starts to break, he *does* start to transform into a werewolf, until Bonnie stops the spell.

As for why Tyler turned so much earlier than Jules, Klaus's witch explains this when she first brings Jules to the sacrifice. The witch has cast a spell on Jules to slow down her transformation, presumably to make it easier to handle her. (Out-of-universe, it was important that Jules be able to talk during her final scene, so she had to remain human longer.)

Even without that, though there have been indications in other cases that the older a werewolf gets, the more control they get over their transformations. Typically it's used to show that older wolves don't suffer as much from their transformations, but it also applies to their behavior, so it may well include how long you can hold the transformation off.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because werewolves turn on the full-moon night, not necessarily at the same time. The exact hour differs from person to person.

Comment: Please provide one or more references proving this statement to be true

Comment: Proving something about a mythical entity may be a little tricky

Comment: @dav1dsm1th proving something about a fictional creature from a TV show we can quote scenes from is less tricky.